# Spanish for "brass"

Tags: vocabulario

What's the difference between **latón** and **azófar**? Both are given by Google as the Spanish for brass. Is there any regional variation in usage? What's the preferred word in daily speech if at all they are exactly the same thing? What would be the word of preference in Mexico?

Comment: Is the first time I hear the word `azófar`. In Spain `latón` is used as far as I know.

Comment: But note that when `brass` is used not for the specific metal, but for a yellowish shiny thing, even if it is made of plastic, then in Spanish you ususally say **bronce** instead of **latón**, at least in Spain (it may depend on the country).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spain, I've never heard *azófar*, but DRAE says both have the same meaning, just different origins, both from Arabic.

On the Internet it seems *latón* is by far the most used: 1180k hits against 29k for *azófar*.

From DRAE:

> latón.
>   (Del ár. lāṭūn, y este del turco altɩn, oro).
>   1. m. Aleación de cobre y cinc, de color amarillo pálido y susceptible de gran brillo y pulimento.
>
> azófar.
>   (Del ár. hisp. aṣṣúfr, y este del ár. clás. ṣufr).
>   1. m. latón.

Comment: This means that RAE recommends *latón* rather than *azófar*. Which is, indeed, a word I'd never heard before. I wouldn't use *azófar* if I wanted to be understood.

Comment: *latón* is the most popular according to [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lat%C3%B3n%2C+az%C3%B3far&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clat%C3%B3n%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caz%C3%B3far%3B%2Cc0) as well.

Answer (score 2):

`Latón` is an alloy of copper and zinc. As in any alloy the proportion of the components can vary, giving many different metals with slightly different properties. These alloys would all be known as `latón`, even if they are different metals used for different things.

A quick search in wikipedia explains that there are 3 main kinds of *latón*, according to the percentage of zinc used (First, second and third order), but potentially there are many others. For example, *similor* designates an alloy with proportion 80/20 copper/Zinc, *metal del príncipe Alberto* an allowy in porportion 84/16 and *crisocola* an alloy that has 82 parts of copper, 6 of zinc and 6 of tin (according to wikipedia, but those numbers don't add well...). Those names would be then different forms to refer specific variations of *latón*.

The *latón* has many different uses, from jewelry to soldering to make wires and coins, etc. Mostly depending on the proportion of zinc they have. The word `latón` can sometimes be used to refer to something as *cheap metal*.

`Azófar` is the same thing, an alloy of copper and zinc. [The word comes from arabic](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?azo.far),  and means *copper*.

So both words mean the same and refer to the same metal. The just have different etymologies.

It is the same case as with the words `azogue` and `mercurio` (think as using the words `quicksilver` and `mercury` to refer to them. Two words, same element), one comes from the vocabulary of the muslim scientists that once lived in Spain.

Comment: Another example: nitrógeno/ázoe.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me, from a Google image search, that `azófar` refers to something made with  brass and not entirely of brass, while latón seems to be just a pure untainted pile of raw brass, ready to be melted without having to remove other solids.

http://www.google.com/search?q=lat%C3%B3n&tbm=isch

http://www.google.com/search?q=az%C3%B3far&tbm=isch

http://etimologias.dechile.net/?azo.far